# Deploy List Workflow in Production Environment

Tags: sharepoint-designer, workflow, deployment, production

I created list workflow using SharePoint Designer.
How to deploy my list workflow in Production environment?

Comment: (http://www.sharepointalex.co.uk/index.php/2012/10/converting-a-list-workflow-to-a-re-usable-workflow/) Can i use this link to convert list workflow to reusable workflow? If i did this i can save my workflow as template and deploy it in my Production Environment. Please suggest your thoughts..

Answer (score 1):

You can try workflow import/export feature to deploy your workflow to your production environment.

Check the following link to import/export your designer workflow:

http://blogs.technet.com/b/wkng/archive/2012/08/21/exporting-and-importing-sharepoint-designer-2010-list-workflow.aspx

Answer (score 0):

Use a migration tool like: **DocAve**, **Metalogix**, **Quest**, etc.

If you can't use a tool, then you have to do a manually:

1. Create a new workflow on the Production site with the same name.  Be
   sure to add a fake condition and one fake activity.  This will
   generate the standard workflow files.
2. Copy the XOML and RULES files from your workflow in Dev (open the folder in SPD2010 and copy these specific files).
3. Paste those files into the workflow folder you created in step 1.
4. Open the workflow again in Prod, and click through all the steps to reassociate each data point (simply click on the item, and it
   will re-associate).
5. If you have any lookups like "Update List Item," then you'll need to manually edit the    XOML file in SPD or Notepad so that you
   can find/replace the GUID of the associated list.  Of course, that
   list must already exist on the Prod site, too.
6. When done, click Finish to publish the workflow with the copied settings, and it should now work.

**Second is:**
Using Save List As template option create List template then after upload this List template to Production Environment.

Comment: I am not having any migration tools. I tried copying workflow files from my dev site to prod site. Files are copied but it does not reflect when i open the workflow in prod site.

Comment: Check GUID of associated List and Task List.

Comment: Yes i verified GUID also. But i can see only the initial test conditions and actions which i gave before copying. Do i need to modify anything else?

Comment: Once you paste XOML and RULES files then save workflow don't publish.

Comment: Yes I saved the workflow files. When i opened the workflow after saving i can't see the updated workflow.